# How to run a custom command create in composer.json with options?

Tags: php, command-line, terminal, composer-php

I'd like to use the Codeception bin file in project A from project B, so in project B's `composer.json` file I have added this script:

```
"codecept": "../projectA/vendor/bin/codecept"
```

With this, I can run a command from project B such as:

```
composer codecept bootstrap
```

However, if I add an option that can be used with the `bootstrap` command, such as:

```
composer codecept bootstrap --empty
```

Composer throws with the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
The "--empty" option does not exist.
```

This is my first time playing around with custom commands, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found it, have to use an extra `--` before passing the option, like this:

```
composer codecept bootstrap -- --empty
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is from Symfony Console that is a dependency of Composer.

The underlying problem is that the command-line argument parser in Symfony Console is flawed (read: limited).

You can work-around that in many cases - but not for all - by using the `--` argument delimiter and adding the commands arguments behind. E.g.:

```
composer codecept bootstrap -- --empty
```

However this does only work for command-line options *that do not exist in Symfony Console as global arguments*. E.g. this won't work for `--help`, it will show Composers' help text. Or `--version`, or `--quiet` and so on and so forth, e.g.:

```
composer exec codecept-the-foo-baloo bootstrap -- --version
Composer version ...
```

The command/package must not even be installed. As written this is flawed and introduces such and similar kind of limitation(s).